# Gorm not reading columns on select

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm running a SELECT using WHERE on gorm but the results are comming with the columns store_name and type empty(""). I have the following struct on Go:

```
type Store struct {
      ID        uint
      StoreName string
      Type      string
      Code      string `gorm:"unique"`
      Active     bool
      CreatedAt *time.Time
      UpdatedAt *time.Time
}
```

The following database on Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stores
(
    id                  BIGSERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    store_name          TEXT            NOT NULL,
    type                TEXT            NOT NULL,
    code                TEXT            NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    active              BOOLEAN         DEFAULT true,
    created_at          TIMESTAMPTZ     NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at          TIMESTAMPTZ
);
```

Im running this select right here:

```
    var store Store

    result := db.First(&stores).Where("code = ?", code)
    if err := result.Error; err != nil {
          return nil, err
    }

    return &stores, nil
```

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong? All columns are returned on the SELECT except for the columns StoreName and Type. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the field tag if field name differs from DB column name.

Example:

```
StoreName string `gorm:"column:store_name"`
```

See this document: https://gorm.io/docs/models.html